# C# cant click on a website button by his ID

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem and I have no idea where its coming from. It has to do with clicking a button by his `ID`. Can someone explain me whats going on?
This is supposed to compare the message that comes from the Client and if that message is `NxEpisode` it will click on that button, but for some reason its not working.

Img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P32ML.jpg

C# Code

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://kissanime.com/Anime/One-Piece/Episode-692");

        System.Threading.Thread newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(serverfunction);
        newThread.Start();


    }
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }


   public void serverfunction()
        {
            int port = 80;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.68");
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            server.Start();


            byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
            string data;


            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                int i;
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Global.message = StripExtended(data);
                if (Global.message == "NxEpisode")
                {
                                        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnNext").InvokeMember("Click");
                }

                }

        }

    static string StripExtended(string arg)
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(arg.Length); //Max length
        foreach (char ch in arg)
        {
            UInt16 num = Convert.ToUInt16(ch);//In .NET, chars are UTF-16
            //The basic characters have the same code points as ASCII, and the extended characters are bigger
            if ((num >= 32u) && (num <= 126u)) buffer.Append(ch);
        }
        return buffer.ToString();
    }





}


    public class Global
    {
        public static string message = "";

    } 





}
```

Html code

```
    <a href="http://kissanime.com/Anime/One-Piece/Episode-692?id=108094">
<img id='btnNext' src="http://kissanime.com/Content/images/next.png" title="Next episode" border="0"/></a>
```

Comment: Please be specific in how it doesn't work.

Comment: I Think i was pretty specific

Comment: No you were not specific. Does it do nothing when you click it? Does it show an error? Does the website crash? See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really know what cause it for not working but try this :

```
<img id='btnNext' name='btnNext' src="http://kissanime.com/Content/images/next.png" title="Next episode" border="0"/></a>
```

if it doesn't work try this also

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img"))
            {
                if (el.Name == "btnNext")
                {
                    el.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
```